# Forecasting a complex time series by splitting into subseries

Tags: time-series, forecasting, excel

I have finance data that I need to forecast out for 7 years.  My data is generally debits and credits, and those are split into a number of sub-series which share common traits (e.g. similar seasonality and/or trend).

My question is, is it appropriate to

1. split the total series into component parts;
2. forecast each part in the most appropriate manner;
3. re-aggregate the parts into a complete projection?

For example, I'd like to treat the following sub-series/parts differently:

**Expenditures**

- Wages/Pension (annual percent increase, based upon contracts)
- Insurance (annual percent increase based upon prior increases)
- Supplies (annual percent increase based upon different prior increases)

Then, add the individual sub-series back into a single forecast.  Obviously, there would be similar but different sub-series/parts for revenue, which would eventually be combined for a total forecast.

Comment: The short answer is yes. The tricky part is getting prediction intervals on the re-aggregated forecasts as your components are probably correlated.

Comment: Did you look at Singular Spectrum Analysis? (R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rssa/index.html). It can be used for decomposition and forecasting of time series.